# I cannot figure out why some of my progress bars work, and the others don't (React TSX)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, user-interface, frontend, logic

Edit: Fixed(sort of?). I have NO idea what the issue was, literally all I did was copy paste the mp bar and modify it to match the hp bar, but it works now? WTF? Think I found a browser bug. Literally no change.

The MP bars update when the state changes, but the HP bars don't. The text updates fine for both. As far as I can tell they work identically.The useeffect and the  text proves that it is updating correctly and IS a number, all the values *are* correct, but it isn't reflecting in my HP progress bars. The values are set in a different component, right now it's just a simple -100 on all the states here as a test. Thoroughly baffled

```
const PlayerComponent: React.FC<PlayerComponentProps> = ({ player, stat_name }) => {

const { KnightMP, setKnightMP } = useContext(KnightMPContext);
const { DmageMP, setDmageMP } = useContext(DmageMPContext);
const { WmageMP, setWmageMP } = useContext(WmageMPContext);
const { RmageMP, setRmageMP } = useContext(RmageMPContext);

const { KnightHP, setKnightHP } = useContext(KnightHPContext);
const { DmageHP, setDmageHP } = useContext(DmageHPContext);
const { WmageHP, setWmageHP } = useContext(WmageHPContext);
const { RmageHP, setRmageHP } = useContext(RmageHPContext);
//ts won't cooperate, so we're YOLO-ing it with any
const MatchToMPState: Map<string, any> = new Map(
    [
        ["knight", KnightMP],
        ["dmage", DmageMP],
        ["wmage", WmageMP],
        ["rmage", RmageMP]

    ]
)
const MatchToHPState: Map<string, any> = new Map(
    [
        ["knight", KnightHP],
        ["dmage", DmageHP],
        ["wmage", WmageHP],
        ["rmage", RmageHP]

    ]
)
useEffect(() => {
    //this is correct, but the hp progress bars are not changing???
    console.log("inside player component", MatchToHPState.get(player))
}, [MatchToHPState.get(player)])
return (
    <>
        <section className='flex flex-row text-white'>
            <h1 className='mr-4 text-xl'>HP</h1>
            <ul className='flex flex-row space-x-4'>
                {UpdateStatusEffects(player)}
            </ul>
        </section>
        <div className='flex flex-row'>
            <progress className='p-hp'
                max={sm[stat_name].get('max-hp')}
                value={
                    MatchToHPState.get(player)}>
            </progress>
            <div className='ml-2 text-xl hp-text'>
                <strong>
                    {MatchToHPState.get(player)}/{sm[stat_name].get('max_hp')}
                </strong>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h1 className='mr-4 text-xl text-white'>MP</h1>
        <div className='flex flex-row'>
            <progress className='mb-4 p-mb p-mp'
                max={sm[stat_name].get('max_mp')}
                value={
                    MatchToMPState.get(player)
                }>
            </progress>
            <div className='ml-2 text-xl mp-text'>
                <strong>
                    {MatchToMPState.get(player)}/{sm[stat_name].get("max_mp")}
                </strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
)
```

}

The issue is likely somewhere else but I did a thorough search of the entire repo and cannot find any reason the MP bars work but the HP ones don't. Types are all number, values are all as expected with both hp and mp and it's not a css issue. As far as I can tell, the contexts work the same. But I'll leave it [here](https://github.com/OblivionNoirV2/shadows-requiem/tree/main/bbv2) if someone else wants to look.